# Metrizing pointwise convergence of *sequences* of functionals in a dual space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

This question was [asked by myself on the math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818474/metrizing-pointwise-convergence-of-sequences-of-functionals-in-a-dual-space) a few days ago. I thought I'd repeat it here:

Let $X$ be a normed, real vector space of uncountable dimension. Let $X^*$ denote the set of all continuous linear functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a metric $d : X^* \times X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ such that a sequence $(\varphi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X^*$ converges to $\varphi$ with respect to $d$ if and only if $\varphi_n(x) \to \varphi(x)$ for all $x \in X$?

I believe the answer to this question is no, but I have been unable to show it.

I am aware that "the topology of pointwise convergence" -- the weak* topology -- is not metrizable. However, there exist distinct topologies which agree on their convergent sequences, so it is possible for such a metric to exist while still inducing a different topology from the weak* topology.

I have seen [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435469/conditions-that-ensure-the-metric-topology-of-e-coincides-with-the-initial-top) which asks a more general question about when the metric topology agrees with the weak topology induced by a family of functions. The answer to this question presents sufficient conditions; I am interested in necessary conditions.

Here's what I know:

- If $X$ has *countable* dimension, then there *does* exist a metric which does this: namely, $d(\varphi, \psi) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{|\varphi(x_n) - \psi(x_n)|}{|\varphi(x_n) - \psi(x_n)|+1}$ where $\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a linear basis of $X$.
- Pointwise convergence on every basis vector implies pointwise convergence everywhere. So, the question may equivalently be stated: "does there exist a metric $d : X^* \times X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_n \to_d \phi$ if and only if $\phi_n(x_i) \to \phi(x_i)$ for all basis vectors $x_i$?"
- When $X$ is separable, such a metric exists on the unit ball (with respect to the operator norm) of $X^*$.

I have tried (without success) to reduce the problem to that of the metrizability of the weak* topology by arguing that any metric which satisfies the desired property must in fact induce the weak* topology. In particular, I have tried to show that the family of open sets $S = \left\{ e_x^{-1}(U) : x \in X, U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ is open} \right\}$ is a subbase for the topology induced by $d$ (here, $e_x$ denotes the evaluation map $f \mapsto f(x)$).

I have also tried to directly derive a contradiction by constructing a sequence of functionals which must converge to zero but do not converge pointwise.

Comment: The subtle aspect of the question is that a metric with the same convergent sequences as the weak$^*$ topology could still generate a different topology. For a Banach space $X$, there is no metric generating the weak$^*$-*uniformity*: The uniform boundedness principle implies that $(X^*,\sigma^*)$ is sequentially complete and then $(X^*,\sigma^*)$ would be a Fréchet space. The open mapping theorem then implies that $\sigma^*$ coinides with the dual norm topology which implies that $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thank you, Jochen, this is very helpful! I don't think I quite understand how the uniform boundedness principle implies completeness, and why the open mapping theorem implies equality of the $\sigma^*$ and dual norm topologies. If we have a Cauchy sequence $\varphi_n$ with respect to a metric $d$ satisfying our condition, how can we ensure that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi_n(x)$ exists for all $x \in X$?

Comment: If $\varphi_n$ is Cauchy for the $\sigma^*$-uniformity, then $\varphi_n(x)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ and hence convergent and, in particular, bounded. The limits $\varphi(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x)$ define a  linear functional which is continuous because of the uniform boundedness theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of that, but I couldn't figure out how to make the argument that $\varphi_n(x)$ is still Cauchy, since we don't know how the metric is actually defined. It certainly seems natural, though; I'll see if I can figure it out. Could you explain how the open mapping theorem is applied?

Comment: The identity $(X*,\|\cdot\|^*) \to (X^*,\sigma^*)$ is continuous and hence has a continuous inverse if the range is a Fréchet space. Recall that this is a site for research problems.